# Timer, Time code, Time format countdown

Tags: timer, basic

I read the data from mysql database with command

```
   vrijeme = myData.Item(2)           ' translation vrijeme = time
           ime = "Dobrodosli " & myData.Item(0) & ""  ' translation ime = name
           GameForma.Show()
```

After that i store the vrijeme to the textbox with

```
txtvrijeme.text = vrijeme
```

Then i add timer control on form and want to countdown from the time in textbox to 0 ..
The time in textbox is in format 00:00:00

Anyway's ill set the entire project in .rar with connection strings and all needed stuffs if anyone want to help
Dropbox :https://www.dropbox.com/s/maxmxeak0cr353q/PocetnaVerzija.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be  . Read the data from value

```
    hours = txtTimefromDB.Text.Substring(0, 2)
    minutes = txtTimefromDB.Text.Substring(3, 2)
    sec = txtTimefromDB.Text.Substring(6, 2)
```

Start decrementing

```
Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
    sec = sec - 1
    If sec = 0 Then
        minutes = minutes - 1
        sec = 60
    ElseIf minutes = 0 Then
        hours = hours - 1
        minutes = 60
    End If
    txtTimefromDB.Text = "" & hours & ":" & minutes & ":" & sec
End Sub
```